# Ignore hidden files while recursively scanning directories

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

How to ignore the hidden files while recursively traversing the directories.
My file structure is of following type:

```
7_jan
├── 7_jan_25_cropped
│   ├── 1.tiff
|
│       
│   
├── 7_jan_50_cropped
│   ├── 1.tiff
│   ├── 10.tiff
│   ├── 11.tiff
│   ├── 12.tiff
│   ├── 13.tiff
│   ├── 14.tiff
│
└── 7_jan_75_cropped
    ├── 1.tiff
    ├── 10.tiff
    ├── 11.tiff
    ├── 12.tiff
```

I am recursively storing each file path so that I can later operate upon them but meanwhile the `.DS_Store` file is also getting stored which I don't want to store. How to remove that?

```
folders = []
files = []
rec_folders = []
for entry in os.scandir('/Users/swastik/csre/dataset'):
    if entry.is_dir():
        folders.append(entry.path)
        for recentry in os.scandir(entry.path):
            if not recentry.path.startswith('.'):
                rec_folders.append(recentry.path)
    elif entry.is_file():
        files.append(entry.path)
print('Folders:')
print(folders)
print('Further files:')
print(rec_folders)
```

Output-

```
 Folders:
 ['/Users/swastik/csre/dataset/7_jan']
 Further folders:
 ['/Users/swastik/csre/dataset/7_jan/7_jan_75_cropped', 
  '/Users/swastik/csre/dataset/7_jan/.DS_Store', 
  '/Users/swastik/csre/dataset/7_jan/7_jan_50_cropped', 
  '/Users/swastik/csre/dataset/7_jan/7_jan_25_cropped']
```

Here , it is also storing the `.DS_Store` file, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just replace `if not recentry.path.startswith('.'):` with `if not recentry.name.startswith('.'):`, so that it will ignore your `.DS_Store` file.